# Why is there a TypeError: Cannot read property 'completed' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I developed a reducer for a todo reactjs app. This is part of the reducer:

```
 case "SHOWCOMPLETE":
            //todo remove
            debugger;
            return state.map(todo => {
                if (todo.completed) {
                    return todo
                }
                else
                {}
            })
```

This is to show the todos which have a completed:true. However the todos component renders this with the error. This is part of the component:

```
if (this.props.todos) {
            //todo remove
            console.log('testing=this.props', this.props);
            display = this.props.todos.map
            (
                    (todo) => (

                        <p className={todo.completed ? 'strikethrough' : ''}
                           onClick={() => this.complete(todo.name)}> {todo.name}!</p>
                    )

            )
        }
```

Why do I get this error? Here is a github link:[github](https://github.com/dimitri-a/reactjs_dutchboiler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually want to do is use `filter` and not `map`. When you use `map` you get:

```js
let a = [1,2,3].map(n=> {if (n !== 2) return n}) 

console.log('a = ', a);  //result = [1, undefined, 3];
```

and `filter` will give you:

```js
let a = [1,2,3].filter(n=> (n !== 2)); 

console.log('a = ', a);  //result = [1, 3]
```

The `undefined` you get when using `map` is passed as a todo and then when accessing `todo.completed` it throws.

See more at:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example